# residue at an essential singularity and the value of the integral

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

the way i calculated was to open the cosine series and then multiply by $z^7$.by doing this i got the value to be $I=1/4!$ .is it correct?please explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is right.

As you said, at $z=0$, the function $f(z)=\cos(\frac{1}{z^2})$ has an essential singularity, that is, all terms in the Laurent series have negative powers of $z$. One aproach (as I think you did), is expanding the series for $\cos(\frac{1}{z^2})$ and multiplying it by $z^7$. Then you can calculate the residue at $z=0$, which is the coefficient $c_{-1}$ that in your case is $\frac{1}{24}$. Then, by the Residue Theorem, you can conclude that $\frac{1}{24}$ is precisely the value of your integral.

However, another useful aproach (in my opinion), is to make the substitution $w=\frac{1}{z}$. Then, $dz=\frac{-dw}{w^2}$ and $z^7=\frac{1}{w^7}$. So

$$I=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}z^7\cos(\frac{1}{z^2})dz=\frac{-1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma^*}\frac{\cos(w^2)}{w^9}dw$$

Where $\gamma*=\{z\in \Bbb{C}: |z|=\frac{1}{2}\}$. Applying Cauchy Integral Formula, you get the result, $I=\frac{1}{24}$.